# Running unit test with CppUnit on a dll

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I have a visual studio project which has CppUnit test cases for one of our modules. This project when built creates a dll (Something like ModuleUnitTest.dll). I am not getting how do I run these tests? Is there any readymade stub available in CppUnit which can read from this dll and run the tests? Or do I have to write my own? Since these unit test cases were available from long time and there is no stub code I believe I need not write one. Can somebody tell me how can I execute the tests from the dll?

Comment: I don't suppose there is a rundll32-complaint entry-point in that DLL?

Comment: @WhozCraig: You mean `main` or `_tmain` ? No

Comment: you need to link that dll into your cppunit project build, and access them in your testcases

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your testing code you need a test runner.  The standard answer is to create a file like CppUnitTestMain.cpp and add code something like this (straight from the cppunit docs):

```
#include <cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h>
#include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
  CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
  CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry &registry = CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry();
  runner.addTest( registry.makeTest() );
  bool wasSuccessful = runner.run( "", false );
  return wasSuccessful;
}
```

Because the TestRegistry information isn't available if this is a separately compiled project, I think you'd end up doing some coding using LoadLibrary to bring in the DLL, then getting the information from it to add to the test runner.  Not impossible, but it's work you'll have to figure out on your own.

But manually handling the test registry is extra work that the macros are supposed to handle for you easily.  That leads to the bigger question I'd ask, which is why are your tests currently housed in a DLL project?  What are you doing with them if they aren't being executed?  Is there some other executable loading and running them that you could leverage?

The answer we normally use is to have the test project itself be an executable, not a DLL, and to contain all the test code.  It statically links the business logic via the linker Additional Dependencies settings: $(SolutionDir)businessProject\debug\obj*.OBJ files, and in the solution we add a project dependency on the main businessProject code being built.

Answer (score 0):

Youse **Test Explorer** floating panel of Visual Studio.