# LabVIEW not responding when I run this code. C++ code issue or LabVIEW issue?

Tags: c++, opencv, labview

For some background, I am compiling in Visual Studio 2019 and running the code inside LabVIEW 2017. The reason I am doing it in LabVIEW is for research to control a robotic gantry. This is the vision system and it is supposed to detect rectangles (wirebond pads for silicon detectors).

I need it to atleast show me a picture or something but when I run it in LabVIEW, it just says it is not responding and makes me hard close the program. So frustrating! If theres no huge errors in my C++ code then I know I have to dig deeper into my LabVIEW code.

The following code is my problem. I am fairly new to C++ and programming in general. I have done the step each line inside LabVIEW and when it stops responding is when it starts to grab the `nominalHeight`, `xfov` etc... or just when it goes into the `WBPdetection` function in general.

Any help is much appreciated. Or if someone could just point me in the right direction.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "WBPdetection.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void show3(cv::Mat img)
{
    cv::namedWindow("MyWindow", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("MyWindow", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyWindow("MyWindow");
}

__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl WBPdetection(
    char* imgPtr, 
    int imgLineWidth, 
    int imgWidth, 
    int imgHeight, 
    double percent_size, 
    double nominalWidth, 
    double nominalHeight,
    double tolerance,
    double xfov,
    double yfov)
{
    cv::Mat img(imgHeight, imgWidth, CV_8U, (void*)imgPtr, imgLineWidth);
    cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(img.cols * percent_size, img.rows * percent_size), 0, 0);

    //PREPPING IMAGE FOR DETECTION ALGORITHIM
    cv::threshold(img, img, 125, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);
    cv::GaussianBlur(img, img, cv::Size(5, 5), 0);
    cv::erode(img, img, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1); 
    cv::dilate(img, img, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 1, 1, 1);
    
    //USE FIND CONTOURS ALGORITHIM
    vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy; 
    cv::findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); 
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) 
    {   approxPolyDP( cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true ); 
        boundRect[i] = cv::boundingRect( cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]) ); 
     }

    vector<vector<double>> dimRects; //ex [ [w1,h1], [w2,h2], [w3,h3], ...]
    vector<cv::Point> centerRects; //ex [ [c1], [c2], [c3], ... ]

    //PUTTING DIMENSIONS OF ALL RECTANGLES IN VECTORS
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Point center = ((boundRect[i].tl().x + boundRect[i].br().x) / 2, (boundRect[i].tl().y + boundRect[i].br().y) / 2); //what about even pixels
        double rectWidth = (boundRect[i].br().x - boundRect[i].tl().x) * (xfov / img.cols); //might not matter tbh
        double rectHeight = (boundRect[i].tl().y - boundRect[i].br().y) * (yfov / img.rows);
        dimRects[i].push_back(rectWidth);
        dimRects[i].push_back(rectHeight);
        centerRects.push_back(center);
    }

    //DEFINING minWidth, etc... FROM tolerance AND nominalWidth
    double minWidth = nominalWidth * (1 - tolerance);
    double maxWidth = nominalWidth * (1 + tolerance);
    double minHeight = nominalHeight * (1 - tolerance);
    double maxHeight = nominalHeight * (1 + tolerance);

  // DRAWING CONTOURS AND BOUNDING RECTANGLE + CENTER
    for( int i = 0; i< dimRects.size(); i++ )
     {
       cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar(255,255,255); //creates color
       if ((dimRects[i][0] > minWidth && dimRects[i][0] < maxWidth) && (dimRects[i][1] > minHeight && dimRects[i][1] < maxHeight)) 
       {
           drawContours(img, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point()); 
           rectangle(img, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0); 
           circle(img, centerRects[i], 1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, cv::LINE_8);
       }
    }

    show3(img);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running your functions using a test runner hosting that dll? This woulld at least be useful for sorting out if it's because of labview or a bug in your code.

Comment: I am posting this after a few days of trying to figure it out myself. I have explored every avenue I can think of where an error can occur but it just still does not work. I've tried rubber duck debugging too. If there's something else I can do or research to solve my problem I am all ears.

Comment: What is a test runner? and what should I do to try it? It atleast builds in VS but when compiling in Labview it breaks. Previous versions of the code have worked with the same Labview set up so its unlikely thats the problem but still possible if my C++ code is fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700184/running-unit-test-with-cppunit-on-a-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is one error here

```
vector<vector<double>> dimRects; 
...
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    ...
    dimRects[i].push_back(rectWidth);
    dimRects[i].push_back(rectHeight);
```

`dimRects` has zero size but your code treats it as if it has the same size as `contours`.

Comment: Would that not put each width and height in the i'th element of the vector? Thank you for the help. I am coming from python and its a big change.

Comment: Well I guess I didn't understand vectors completely, I thought you could just add stuff in and don't need say how big they are like with arrays. Thank you very much. It worked and the happiness I feel can't be explained in words.

Comment: @jfwinston32 Go [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) next time, you feel you didn't understand something completely.

Comment: @jfwinston32 Glad to help but your previous code is self contradictory, by using `[i]` you are assuming that you can just add stuff in the first dimension, but in the second dimension you are doing it the correct way with `push_back`. Push back (or the equivalent) is needed in both dimensions.